# How find this $aA_{m+1}=\overline{\sigma_{0}\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}\cdots\sigma_{m}}$

Tags: number-theory, permutations, number-systems

**Question**

> let $m$ is positive numbers,and such $m\ge 5$,and  $$A_{m+1}=\overline{1234\cdots m}=1\times (m+1)^{m-1}+2\times (m+1)^{m-2}+\cdots+(m-1)\times (m+1)+m$$(or see (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation)

and positive integer number $a$ such
$$\gcd{(a,m)}=1,\left[\dfrac{a}{m}\right]=\left[\dfrac{a}{m+1}\right]$$

> show that:
>   $$aA_{m+1}=\overline{\sigma_{0}\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}\cdots\sigma_{m}}$$
>   where a permutation $\sigma_{0},\sigma_{1},\sigma_{2},\cdots,\sigma_{m}$ of $0,1,2,3,\cdots,m$ is alternating.and $[x]$ is  the largest integer not greater than x.

My idea: since $$\left[\dfrac{a}{m}\right]=\left[\dfrac{a}{m+1}\right]\le\dfrac{a}{m+1}$$
then we have 
$$\left[\dfrac{a}{m}\right]\le a-m\left[\dfrac{a}{m}\right]$$
let $a=pm+r,p,r\in N,0\le r<m$,then we have
$$p\le r<m$$.
then I can't. I fell this reslut is interesting, I don't know somepaper have this reserch?Thank you for you help

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the notation, $\overline{1234\cdots m}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson，hello,can see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation

Comment: If $m=9,a=70$, we have $\lfloor70/10\rfloor=\lfloor70/9\rfloor$ and $A_{10}\times70=123456789\times70=8641975230$, which is a permutation but it is not alternating. Am I missing something?

Comment: So, the notation seems to mean, 1234...m, interpreted to base $m+1$. Why not just say that? And what is the $n$ in $A_{n+1}$? It doesn't seem to appear anywhere else in the question.